# Load data to a data set from data table in C#

Tags: c#

I have a dataset called "dts_Material_Report" which is used to generate reports.In that data set I have a tableAdapter called "dt_report_Received_Materials".

Previously I have load the data to that table adapter with following code ,

```
private void generate_report( string qry )
    {

        string query, qry1;
        query = qry;
        int pr_id = Form_Common_PCM.pr_id;            

        clz_Common_SqlConnection con = new clz_Common_SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con.ActiveCon());
        DataSet dts = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(dts, "dt_report_Received_Materials");            


        rdc.SetDataSource(dts);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdc;
        crystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
        crystalReportViewer1.Show();
    }
```

But currently I am having all the data which I need to generate the report in one of my data table called "dt_mat_cost".

```
int Ref_ID_s_category;
            Ref_ID_s_category = Convert.ToInt16(cbo_sub_category .SelectedValue );
            int pro_id = Form_Common_PCM.pr_id;
            clz_Received_Material_Summary rms = new clz_Received_Material_Summary();
            DataTable dt_mat_cost = rms.Summary_Material_Cost_Filter_By_Project_By_Sub_Category(Ref_ID_s_category);
```

Now i want to load those data from "dt_mat_cost" to my tableAdapter "dt_report_Received_Materials" .Is there any way to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, if you want to replace a DataTable in a DataSet with another DataTable you could first remove the old and then add the new.

Comment: The generate_report() method looks like it will force you to write code that is horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this would be to put the DataTable into a DataSet and then run the crystal code as shown below.  You may be able to just set the ReportSource to the datatable but I do not recall off the top of my head if that will work.

```
DataTable dt_matCost = rms.Summary_Material_Cost_Filter_By_Project_By_Sub_Category(Ref_ID_s_category);

DataSet dts = new DataSet();
dts.Tables.Add(dt_matCost);
//ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Whatever CR thinks it is"; // may need to set for CR

rdc.SetDataSource(dts);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdc;
crystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
crystalReportViewer1.Show();
```